# Resharper - Inconclusive: test not run on debugging

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, visual-studio-2019

I have an issue very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311108/test-method-is-inconclusive-test-wasnt-run-error) one.

Debugging any test in Resharper returns `"Inconclusive: test not run"`. This occurs for every test, every solution, every project at my machine. Reinstalling VS2019 and Resharper didn't help. Running tests works fine.

[image]
I've debugged test using `devenv.exe /ReSharper.LogFile C:\temp\resharper.log /ReSharper.LogLevel Verbose` command and the result is [this](https://pastebin.com/4KHeb25K) (a fragment of ~6900 lines file).

The first error says: `“Method 'StartSessionAsync' in type 'ReSharperAwareWrapper' from assembly 'JetBrains.ReSharper.UnitTesting.MSTest.Provider, Version=777.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325' does not have an implementation.”`

I tried all the popular answers in the post I've linked and nothing seems to help.

Code is .NET Core 3.1 based C# solution.

Resharper: 2020.1.4 | Visual Studio: 16.7.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've solved an issue by installing [2020 EAP version of resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/nextversion/#section=windows) (2020.2 EAP). Seems like it's a bug in 2020.1.4 version.

Comment: I updated from Resharper 2020.1.4 to 2020.2.4 and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Nice one, suspending Resharper fixed the issue! Thanks.

Comment: I updated from ReSharper 2020.1.4 to 2021.1.2 and it fixed it for me.  Had to restart Visual Studio after update for the fix to work.

Comment: Same problem with ReSharper 2021 1.1. Update 1.2 did it.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was because the test was unchecked at build time. So I had to checked the Unit Test projects in
Build -> Configuration Manager . check column build.

Answer (score 1):

I started to have exactly the same issue after i updated VS to 16.7. Funny thing is that it broke unit test debugging in Rider as well.
Microsoft has pushed new `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` package, but looks like it does not help. As a workaround, you can launch test from VS Unit Test window, instead of Resharper's one.

Answer (score 0):

As @Peace says, you can update ReSharper, but if that does not help you can:

1. Reboot
2. Update Visual Studio: **Help > Check for Updates**

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given by @Mihails Popovs. Possible cause is that you do not have referenced the Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.

Answer (score 0):

This is just ReSharper's "default error message" if it somehow failed to run a test. As you can see in [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311108/test-method-is-inconclusive-test-wasnt-run-error) (of which this one is basically a duplicate), there are hundreds of possible causes, and you will find more if you search outside of StackOverflow.

In the upper right corner of the "Test Sessions" window, there is an "Errors" button where you can click to see detailed error logs, which may give you some hints. Most people overlook this button because of its size and location (also, why not just show the logs on the right hand side where the test output normally is shown?)

Some common things you can always try:

- Clear caches in ReSharper settings and restart Visual Studio
- Run the unit test project directly from Visual Studio. Does this work? If not, then obviously, your unit tests also cannot run (but it would be great if ReSharper reported this in a clearer way...)

Overall, poor error reporting in the test sessions UI of the ReSharper test runner is the reason people get frustrated and stuck with issues like this, and it has been like this for over a decade.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this out of a sudden for tests in some projects. In VS did Build->Clean and a rebuild. Then tests worked again.