# "The XamarinTelemetry task failed unexpectedly" on second build

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

With the latest VS preview (VS 17.3 Preview 3), with both Android and iOS, building my application works the first time I build it, but the second time it fails with

> The "XamarinTelemetry" task failed unexpectedly.

Looking at the logs I see this:

```
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018: The "XamarinTelemetry" task failed unexpectedly.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018: File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySessionSettings.GetFaultEventBucketFilterJson(List`1 bucketFilters)
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySessionSettings.ToString()
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySession.SerializeSettings()
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Common.Tasks.Telemetry.GetSession(IBuildEngine4 buildEngine, String vsTelemetrySession) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.Common.Tasks\Telemetry.cs:line 62
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Common.Tasks.XamarinTelemetry.Execute() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.Common.Tasks\XamarinTelemetry.cs:line 31
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018: 
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018: WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018: To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018: Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018: To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets(138,9): error MSB4018:
```

The only workaround I've found is to clean the entire solution and rebuild, which succeeds, but then fails again the next time I try to build.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: I have also experienced this issue with the Visual Studio 2022 17.3 version (Windows)

Comment: It's amazing how often the xamarin team can break the build toolchain 

Comment: Same here. Did not have this problem in VS 2019

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First off, don't shoot the messenger here..

**UPDATE: August 16, 2022**

> According to Visual Studio v17.3.1's [Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1731--visual-studio-2022-version-1731), this issue has been resolved.  However, if not, there's still the following

As per the workaround thread on Visual Studio's dev community thread:

> 1. Open, `Xamarin.Sdk.targets` in Admin Mode (*I use, Notepad++*)
>
>    - `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Msbuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets`
> 2. Comment out the `<XamarinTelemetry ... />`
> 3. Save file and rebuild the solution.

Though it does work in the interim, please forward your official feedback on the official VS Developer Community thread in the link below.

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unexpecter-error-of-task-Xamarin-Teleme/10096527
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XamarinTelemetry-task-failed-unexpectedl/10100083

Comment: this works well, but the telemetry comes back from the dead. Not sure what causes it to re-emerge but if it stops working check there again.

Comment: I'm with you. So far, it's been playing well for me so far. But at least it's a quick bandaid until MS addresses the real issue.

Comment: what is XamarinTelemetry  for? are they reporting things secretly? :D

Comment: FYI it fixes it for me on the just release VS2022 - Maui ready ;)

Comment: Removed the error for me as well in Visual Studio 2022 v. 17.3.  But will commenting this out have any repercussion during archive deployment to the app stores?

Comment: Just a warning that this error does still occur periodically in 17.3 and even still in 17.4 preview. I've been using 17.3 previews for a while, and it seems to be something in the last couple of weeks that it's really become a problem, I think the telemetry backend is the problem, not the target itself, but removing the target is probably the easiest "fix".

Answer (score 2):

There are several config files in the VS installation which reference 13.0.0.0

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
```

I replaced these with

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.1.0" newVersion="13.0.1.0" />
```

and was able to build.
It seems that the 13.0.0.0 is not publicly available as nuget package...

Comment: Unfortunately, while this works and allows the project to build without cleaning, it leads to lots of warnings and other issues (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311108/test-method-is-inconclusive-test-wasnt-run-error))

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 17.3.0, I right-clicked on the projects and selected "Clean".

Then I tried again to right-click the project and selected "Build" and it worked, the "The XamarinTelemetry task failed unexpectedly" error did not occur.

This is in a solution that contains a .NET Standard 2.0 library that references Xamarin Forms and the project in question is an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API referencing the library.

Comment: This was mentioned in the question...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this today and all I did was rebuild the solution, clicked the "save all", closed the application and opened it again but it did not work. I rebuilt the project but it did not work either. So again, I just repeat the process by closing the visual studio, rebuild and run 2 times (also I went to the error file just viewed it) and it works fine. I don't know what differences it made but it works when you repeat the process.

Edit: The error is still repeating. I just use the ***Factory Reset*** when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

There are fixed minor-version editions of VS available, for example "2022 LTSC  17.2".

Install it parallel to your current VS or exclusively.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history#evergreen-bootstrappers

Direct downloads:

- [Enterprise 2022 - 17.2 LTSC](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release.ltsc.17.2/vs_enterprise.exe)
- [Professional 2022 - 17.2 LTSC](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release.ltsc.17.2/vs_professional.exe)
- Community is not available

I prefer this over the modification of your 17.3 installation.

It also appears with a different name, so it's easy to distinguish.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| start menu | [image] |
| VS installer | [image] |

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with my Xamarin forms solution, after upgrading from 17.2 to 17.3.
Today I installed 17.3.2. A dozen builds later and it seems that the issue has been addressed.