# Updated VS 2022 to 17.3 and now get XamarinTelementry Error

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I just updated my VS 2022 to v17.3 and now I get the subject error when compiling a (formally) working iOS app.  The error message is:

```
Error       The "XamarinTelemetry" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,     Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySessionSettings.GetFaultEventBucketFilterJson(  List`1 bucketFilters)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySessionSettings.ToString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.TelemetrySession.SerializeSettings()
   at Xamarin.Common.Tasks.Telemetry.GetSession(IBuildEngine4 buildEngine, String vsTelemetrySession) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.Common.Tasks\Telemetry.cs:line 62
   at Xamarin.Common.Tasks.XamarinTelemetry.Execute() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\MSBuild\Xamarin.Common.Tasks\XamarinTelemetry.cs:line 31
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I tried installing the latest version of Newtonsoft.Json even though I don't use it, but that didn't work, also tried just referencing the Newtonsoft.Json.dll, still didn't work.  Tried cleaning and rebuilding, didn't work.  I couldn't find any other suggestions out there, so I'm kinda at a loss as how to proceed.  Anyone know whats going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The XamarinTelemetry task failed unexpectedly" on second build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73094320/the-xamarintelemetry-task-failed-unexpectedly-on-second-build)

Comment: Yes it did.  Wow ... how did I miss that one.  Put it as your answer so I can mark it.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll help Dennis put it as an answer as it's helpful for others facing the same issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73094320/the-xamarintelemetry-task-failed-unexpectedly-on-second-build), you can try steps below to resolve the issue.

> 1.Open, Xamarin.Sdk.targets in Admin Mode (I use, Notepad++)
>
> - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2022\Preview\Msbuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Sdk.targets
>
> 2.Comment out the <XamarinTelemetry ... />
>
> 3.Save file and rebuild the
> solution.